# React: How to paste characters across multiple inputs in a multi-input component when inputs have variable character limits

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built an input component for a card number or a 2fa code. The component is made with multiple inputs and I have a prop `inputCharLimit` where I can set how many characters can each input take.

The issue that I am facing is that I can't figure out how to paste a code and distribute it properly if the `inputCharLimit` is > 1.

So far I have this function `handlePaste` which works fine if `inputCharLimit` is 1.

```
  const handlePaste = (event, index) => {
    const pastedText = event.clipboardData.getData('text');
    const newValues = Array.from({ length: numberOfInputs }).map((_, i) => {
      if (i < index) {
        return inputValues[i];
      } else if (i === index) {
        return pastedText.slice(0, 1);
      } else if (i < index + pastedText.length) {
        return pastedText.slice(i - index, i - index + 1);
      } else {
        return inputValues[i - pastedText.length + 1];
      }
    });
    setInputValues(newValues);
  };
```

Can you please help me find a way to distribute the pasted text in a correct way. Right now if I paste `111222333444` it will be pasted like so `123 124 134 234`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
const MultiStepForm = ({
  numberOfInputs = 4,
  value,
  onChange,
  inputCharLimit = 1,
}) => {
  const inputArray = Array.from({ length: numberOfInputs });
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState(
    value.split('').map((digit) => Number(digit))
  );

  const inputRef = useRef([]);

  const setInputRef = (index, input) => {
    inputRef.current[index] = input;
  };

  const handleInputChange = (index, event) => {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    const currentInput = inputRef.current[index];
    const nextInput = inputRef.current[index + 1];

    setInputValues((prevValues) => {
      const newValues = [...prevValues];
      newValues[index] = newValue;
      return newValues;
    });

    if (currentInput.value.length === currentInput.maxLength) {
      if (nextInput) {
        nextInput.focus();
        nextInput.value = newValue;
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(inputValues.join(''));
  }, [inputValues, onChange]);

  const handlePaste = (event, index) => {
    const pastedText = event.clipboardData.getData('text');
    const newValues = Array.from({ length: numberOfInputs }).map((_, i) => {
      if (i < index) {
        return inputValues[i];
      } else if (i === index) {
        return pastedText.slice(0, 1);
      } else if (i < index + pastedText.length) {
        return pastedText.slice(i - index, i - index + 1);
      } else {
        return inputValues[i - pastedText.length + 1];
      }
    });
    setInputValues(newValues);
  };

  // const handlePaste = (event, index) => {
  //   const pastedText = event.clipboardData.getData('text');
  //   const newValues = [...inputValues];
  //   for (let i = 0; i < numberOfInputs; i++) {
  //     const pastedCharacters = pastedText.split(i, inputCharLimit);
  //     newValues[numberOfInputs] = pastedCharacters;
  //   }
  //   setInputValues(newValues);
  // };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <form>
              <input
                style={{ width: `${inputCharLimit}ch` }}
                key={index}
                type='tel'
                maxLength={inputCharLimit}
                aria-label={`Credit card digit ${index + 1}`}
                id={`cc-${index + 1}`}
                required
                pattern={`[0-9]{${inputCharLimit}}`}
                ref={(input) => setInputRef(index, input)}
                value={inputValues[index] || ''}
                onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(index, event)}
                onKeyDown={(event) => onKeyDown(event, index)}
                onPaste={(event) => handlePaste(event, index)}
              />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MultiStepForm;
```

Comment: I think you can do that by just changing `pastedText.slice(0, 1)` to `pastedText.slice(0, inputCharLimit)` and `pastedText.slice(i - index, i - index + 1)` to `pastedText.slice(inputCharLimit * i, inputCharLimit * (i + 1))`